# Sygic current user location issue (Android)

Tags: android, sygic

I've a problem with SYGIC SDK in ANDROID, it works fine, the map appears the static pins too but I can't display the pin of my current position in the map.

I followed this [guide](https://www.sygic.com/developers/sygic-maps-sdk/android/getting-started) to work on it.

I'm not sure but I suppose that the problem is coming from the gradle import :
**implementation 'com.sygic.sdk:sdk-release:2.12.8@aar'**
it used to work when I added transitive=true to the cradle import ,but I removed the latter because it caused some dependency problems and ever since then ,the location engine doesn't work,
is it because **transitive=true** is missing ?

Is there anyone who encountred this problem ?

Comment: "Hi guys", sorry I forgot it :)